# Python Modules, passing values to args

Tags: python

Im learning python and am currently trying to pass values from input to the args for a module I wrote but I have no idea how to start.

Can someone give me some advice?

**This is the module im calling**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Employee:
    'Practice class'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, salary):
            self.salary = salary
            Employee.empCount += 1
    def displayCount(self):
            print "Total Employees %d" % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
            print "Salary: ", self.salary


class Att(Employee):
    'Defines attributes for Employees'
    def __init__(self, Age, Name, Sex):
            self.Age = Age
            self.Name = Name
            self.Sex = Sex

    def display(self):
            print "Name: ", self.Name + "\nAge: ", self.Age,  "\nSex: ", self.Sex
```

**This is the code im using to call and pass the values to the args in the above module**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Employee

def Collection1():
    while True:
            Employee.Age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
            if Employee.Age == str(Employee.Age):

                    print "You entered " + Employee.Age + " Please enter a number"
            elif Employee.Age  > 10:
                    break
            elif Employee.Age > 100:
                    print "Please enter a sensible age"
            else:
                    print "Please enter an age greater than 10"
    return str(Employee.Age)

def Collection2():
    Employee.Name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    return Employee.Name


def Collection3():
    while True:
            Employee.Sex = str(raw_input("Are you a man or a woman? "))
            if Employee.Sex == "man":
                    Employee.Sex = "man"
                    return Employee.Sex
                    break
            elif Employee.Sex == "woman":
                    Employee.Sex = "woman"
                    return Employee.Sex
                    break
            else:
                    print "Please enter man or woman "
Attributes = Employee.Employee()

Collection1()
Collection2()
Collection3()


Attributes.displayEmployee()
```

Im guessing I need to take the input from the user and place it in the variables of the class. I tried that but im guessing im doing everything wrong??

Comment: Capitalized member/module/variable/function names are unpythonic. The only capitalized words in your code should be `Employee` and `Att`

Comment: And `Employee.Age == str(Employee.Age)` will always be false - an integer never equals its string representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Employee.Age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))`
There's no use to setting a variable in the module instead of using a local variable, and setting whatever you need to set **outside** the Collection1() function. Note that you are **not** setting the employee (object) atributes', but the module's - this is probably not what you want. Also, functions, by convention, should be named with initial lowercase.

Your inheritance model is a bit strange. Why are the employee attributes in a different (sub) class? Generally, the attributes go into the main class constructor. If you **really** want to use a separate class for the attributes, you shouldn't use a subclass at all in this case.

**EDIT**
Here's what I think you meant to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, salary, age, name, sex):
            self.salary =   salary
            self.age=       age
            self.name=      name
            self.sex=       sex
            #Employee.empCount += 1 #don't do this. you should count instances OUTSIDE

    def __str__(self):
            return "Employee<Name: {0}, Age: {1}, Sex: {2}, Salary: {3}>".format( self.name, self.age, self.sex, self.salary)



def getAge():
    while True:
        try:
            s=raw_input("How old are you? ")
            age = int(s)
            if age > 100:
                print "Please enter a sensible age"
            elif age<=10:
                print "Please enter an age greater than 10"
            else:
                return age
        except ValueError:
            print "You entered " + s + " Please enter a number"

def getName():
    return raw_input("What is your name? ")


def getSex():
    while True:
        sex = str(raw_input("Are you a man or a woman? "))
        if not sex in ("man", "woman"):
            print "Please enter man or woman "
        else:
            return sex



age= getAge()
name= getName()
sex= getSex()
salary=100000

employee = Employee(salary, age, name, sex)
print employee
```

if you want the Employee in a different file (module), just put it there and from your main code run `from Employee import Employee` (the first is the module, the second is the class).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The modules are abit strange as I built one class for practice the created another to practice inheritance etc. Could you give me an example bit of code on how I set the args values for the module?

Comment: Can anyone help me out with what im trying to acheive? How do i make the raw_input data into an arg for the module im calling?

Comment: @k3eper check answer edit. Also, for future questions like this, you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @goncalopp can you please explain this to me def __str__(self): ?

Comment: I also notice the "print employee" line refers to the def __str__(self):, how does it know to print that line if you didnt refer to it by its name __str__(self): I know these must be stupid questions but I really do want to understand and learn python.

Comment: @k3eper check http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__ . If you're just starting out, I advise you to complete the python tutorial at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ . The "Classes" chapter also briefly mentions this technique

Comment: @goncalopp Might I quickly ask, what's the difference between SE and codereview? Both seem to want to avoid chit chat/opinion but rather to focus on code questions? noob query but I only want to put my questions in the right forum. Thanx

Comment: @Dee codereview, as the name suggests, is for asking people to suggest improvements to your code style/structure/correctness, while SO is strictly for problems that you're struggling with while programming

Comment: @goncalopp Thanks, I'm blushing now for not really bothering to do that which I ask of others, think it through. I guess I was surprised that such a practise is not what is (considered to be) done here. thanks for the distinction. So it really is ok to just slap one's program down in codereview and hope to be instructed as to methods it could be improved - at my deteriorated level of coding I think I should avail myself of it post haste. Now that I feel like the waste of the amoeba that inhabits the crud on the sole of a newbie's shoe... ;)